# Image cache won't display new edited image

Tags: php, caching, gd

I am building a php script to write texts over an background image. 
I used GD functions like `imagecopy(), imagejpeg(), imagedestroy()` to merge save text image and the background image. Everything is working perfectly. Upon form submit, the new image will be saved in the same file name of the background image and so on page reload, the edited image is not showing on the browser. It needs me to refresh the page using ctrl + F5(on windows) to load the edited image. Can anyone help me how to clear that cache?

Comment: "Can anyone help me how to clear that cache?" - What do you mean by this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add ?v=something to background path everytime you edit your background image, it will force refresh

Comment: i am not loading the image from php. Loading an BG image on html page(using img tag), let the user to add text(image text) over the BG image and using php to merge and save the image. Reloading page after save and it shows old unedited BG image until i hit ctrl+F5

Comment: ah this one. just add ?v=something to bgpath everytime you edit your background image, it will force refresh

Answer (score 1):

To handle image caching properly, you can write a rules either in your apache configuration or htaccess... or you can create simple "image provider", something like...

```
public function img($imgfile = '')
{
    $imgfile = $_GET['q'];
    $age = 60*60*24*31;
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$imgfile;

    if ( ! file_exists($file))
    {
       header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    }
    else
    {
       $last_modified = filemtime($file);

        // Check for cached version
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) OR isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'])) 
        {
           if ($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] == gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $last_modified)) 
           {
               header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
               exit;
           }
        }   
        if(strpos($imgfile,'.png') !== FALSE)
        {
            Header('Content-Type: image/png');
        }
        elseif(strpos($imgfile,'.jpg') !== FALSE || strpos($img_file,'.jpeg') !== FALSE)
        {
            Header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
        }
        elseif(strpos($img_file,'.gif') !== FALSE)
        {
            Header('Content-Type: image/gif')
        }

        Header('Last-Modified : '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $last_modified));
        Header('Cache-Control : max-age='.$age.', must-revalidate');
        Header('Expires : '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $last_modified + $age));
        echo file_get_contents($file);
}
```

Then you can use that in your image tag, like `<img src="provider.php?q=foo.jpg" alt="Foo" />`